# Retrieve values stored in xml on webpage using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xml-serialization

I've created this `XML` file in visual studio asp.net application, i want to display the values of the element on `Page_Load` using Classes. These are my `XML` code. As a beginner this is what i have so far

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Cars>
  <adStarCar>
    <unqNumber>23260</unqNumber>
    <lasMute>2017-02-28</lasMute>
    <DealSafer>
      <name>Gabe T</name>
      <email>gabriel@gmail.com</email>
    </DealSafer>
     <car>
       <carNumber>87-98-AE</carNumber>
       <company>Audi</company>
       <model>A8</model>
     </car>
   <image>
    <imgBig>http://srv2.betterparts.org/images/audi-a8-01.jpg</imgBig>
    <imgBig>http://buyersguide.caranddriver.com/media/assets/submodel/7710.jpg</imgBig>
   </image>
  </adStarCar>
<adStarCar>
<unqNumber>8955</unqNumber>
<lasMute>2017-01-13</lasMute>
<DealSafer>
  <name>Richard A</name>
  <email>richard@gmail.com</email>
</DealSafer>
<car>
  <carNumber>78-KL-85</carNumber>
  <company>Mercedes</company>
  <model>Maybach</model>
</car>
<image>
  <imgBig>http://blog.caranddriver.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Mercedes-Maybach-S600-Pullman-Guard-PLACEMENT-626x382.jpg</imgBig>
  <imgBig>http://zombdrive.com/images/maybach-11.jpg</imgBig>
</image>
```

Comment: what ist your xml code??

Comment: how can i paste? i tried pasting my code but it didn't work

Comment: Press ctrl+k and paste code.. its actually pretty easy

Comment: But I think xml-code will not be enough though - you should provide more information

Comment: more information?

Comment: which kind of information you need? How to build your classes, how to get XML-Info in code, how to display?
And one more thing which was important to me: You should make your examples anonymous! It looks like you took an existing one... just fyi

Comment: how to build my classes indeed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136938/discussion-between-gabriel-takyie-and-joshit).

Answer (score 0):

I would say you should start with [C# Foreach XML Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144962/c-sharp-foreach-xml-node)

There you´ll find a few examples how to work with C# and XML.

Second you should think about your classes: If you want to create class based on your XML I´ll recommend classes StarCar, DealSafer and Car. Car has attributes Number, Manufacturer, ImageUrl and Model, DealSafer has Name and Email and StarCar has UnqNumber, LastMute DealSafer and Car. Your StarCar-class needs a constructor like

```
public StarCar()
{
    DealSafer = new DealSafer();
    Car = new Car();
}
```

I don´t know where you want to populate the XML-Values, but a populate-method can look similar to the examples from my link. You should create a `List<StarCar>` of StarCars and after that you can create a new StarCar and add to list foreach starCar in your XML.